# Error : clicking on add input controls in jasper server

Tags: jboss5.x, jasperserver

Environment Description:

**- Application server is JBoss eap 5.1, database used is Postgresql9.2,
   OS is Redhat Enterprise Server 6.2**

**- Jasper report server 5.1**

**- Integrated with Active Directory**

Most of the functionality of the jasper server is working fine. I can run report, create new report .All this functionality is working.

I can add input control in iReport but not in jasper server.**But when i am trying to add new input control in jasper server i am getting exceptions.**

Exception list:

**.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name**

**.javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file**

**.java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file**

***Please let me know why i gettting this error. What is solution for this.***

**Error trace:**

> Unknown Object Server Error
>
> The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
>
> **Error Message**
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name
>   'modules/addResource/jasperReport/locateControlResource'; URL
>   [/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/addResource/jasperReport/locateControlResource.jsp]
>
> **Error Trace**
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name
>   'modules/addResource/jasperReport/locateControlResource'; URL
>   [/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/addResource/jasperReport/locateControlResource.jsp]
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:191)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.doEnter(ViewState.java:186)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
>   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
>   at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545) at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
>
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated
>
> **> Error Message**
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated
>   class file
>
> **> Error Trace**
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated
>   class file at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:127)
>   at
>   com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:56)
>
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:76)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>
> **> Error Message**
>
> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
>
> **> Error Trace**
>
> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634) at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205) at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:135)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:67)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:249)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
>   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Answer for this:

I would suggest that you should try to: 
- clear the work folder on JBoss application server (in this folder could be stored the compiled version of the page that caused this stack trace)

For JBoss 6.0 deployment, it might be in

> **jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\tmp\work\jboss.web\default-host\jasperserver-pro**

For JBoss 7.1 deployment, it might be in

> **jboss-7.1\standalone\tmp\work\jboss.web\default-host\jasperserver-pro.**

Please clarify the actual location of this folder in your system  and delete the data .